# Save PDF file to server

Tags: php, perl, pdf, www-mechanize

Save a dynamically generated PDF file from a URL to disk.
The PDF file is generated using ASPX on a url, sample url -

I have tried the basic file_get_contents but it saves an empty file.

```
http://url-address/LabReport_Interface.aspx?TestID=LSHHI764&PID=LSHHI637515&LedgerTransactionNo=401411000222

$handle = fopen("./reports/test.pdf", "wb"); 
if (fwrite($handle, file_get_contents($url)) === FALSE) { 
        echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)"; 
} 
fclose($handle);
```

Thanks in advance.
Any other turnaround would also be appreciated.

Comment: The page that is called has a form, which submits and gives the PDF, how to go to that page using curl or maybe perl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, I used a perl call from php and saved pdf using perl's www-mechanize

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use WWW::Mechanize;

my $url = $ARGV[0];
my $filename = $ARGV[1];

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

$mech->get($url);
$mech->success();
$mech->save_content($filename);
```